# Comparing two different files from Separate Folders with different extensions and opening one with pywinauto

Tags: python-3.x, pywinauto

I am trying to compare two different files from separate folders with different extensions and then trying to open one file with pywinauto. The application opens however the files with the extension that i am mentioning does not open.

I tried to iterate over multiple files it did not work i gave a specific file name. Just the application opens.

Below is the code that i have tried.

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
import os
app = Application(backend="uia").start('C:\Program Files (x86)\Datawatch Monarch 14\DWMonarch.exe')
#app.Dialog.print_control_identifiers()
path = (r'C:\Check\Monarch\ICRDIS.dprj')
path2 = (r'C:\DOLV\ICRDIS.txt')

name1 = path.rsplit('.', 1)[0] 
name2 = path2.rsplit('.', 1)[0]

#for name1 in path:
 #   for name2 in path2:
if name1 == name2:
    try:
        print(name1)
        app.Dialog.child_window(title="Open", auto_id="Open", control_type="SplitButton")
        app.Dialog.child_window(title="File", auto_id="PART_ApplicationButton", control_type="Button")
        app.Dialog.Menu.Open(path.dprj)
                #app.Dialog.Open('name1.dprj')
    except:
        print("No File Name Matches")
```

This is the control identifiers for Monarch with the Open Option:

```
 Menu - 'Ribbon'    (L-4, T30, R1924, B171)
   | ['RibbonMenu', 'Ribbon', 'Menu']
   | child_window(title="Ribbon", auto_id="MainRibbon", control_type="MenuBar")
   |    | 
   |    | Separator - ''    (L26, T1, R29, B21)
   |    | ['17', 'Separator3']
   |    | child_window(auto_id="beforeSeparator", control_type="Separator")
   |    | 
   |    | SplitButton - 'Open'    (L31, T-3, R72, B25)
   |    | ['OpenSplitButton', 'Open', 'SplitButton', 'SplitButton0', 'SplitButton1']
   |    | child_window(title="Open", auto_id="Open", control_type="SplitButton")
```

Couple of questions how do i open the specific application using the mentioned controls and iterate over multiple files.

What am i doing incorrect for this not to work? Please suggest.

Regards,
Ren.

Comment: I'd recommend reading the core concept first: [Getting Started Guide](https://pywinauto.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html). You forgot to call actions for `child_window` specifications (`.invoke()` or `.click_input()`). Also `os.path.splitext()` is useful instead of `rsplit`. And what `path.dprj` means? Please learn how deal with strings in Python. Generally the question looks like "please debug this code", very close to offtopic on StackOverflow.

Comment: Also it's not clear what "comparing" means? It's kind of comparing 2 folders from "explorer.exe" context menu by KDiff3, for example? Or in some specific software? More details are always better. Maybe some screenshots would be useful.

Comment: Hi @VasilyRyabov There are two files in different folders. ICRDIS.dprj and the same file ICRDIS.txt in the other folder. If the names of these two files match excluding the extension. I want to open the ICRDIS.dprj file extension. dprj is the extesnion you get when you are using Datawatch Monarch.  Do let me know incase you need more details.

Comment: First it's not clear which line fails. And which error output a.k.a. traceback is printed. This is always should be provided for obvious Python errors.

Comment: The error is that the file with dprj extension does not open. Just the application opens and it stops no error message

Comment: OK, then print what is returned by every line. `app.Dialog.child_window(title="Open", auto_id="Open", control_type="SplitButton")` does nothing because it just returns WindowSpecification object. Read the guide first to know how to call an action.

Comment: If you are referring to an action like this `app.Dialog.Open.Click()`. I tried it and go this error earlier. 
`ElementNotFoundError: {'best_match': 'Dialog', 'backend': 'uia', 'process': 17196}` Also i tired this `app.Window_(best_match='Dialog', top_level_only=True).child_window(best_match='Open').Click()`  and get the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181508/discussion-between-ren-lyke-and-vasily-ryabov).

Comment: Sorry I’m typing from phone. There is no chat app. Try print([w.window_text() for w in app.windows()]) first. What it shows?

Comment: Tried it and got this result. ['Datawatch Monarch™'].

Comment: Thanks for checking. I tried this in the mean time `file_open = os.path.join(monarch_files,jobname + "." + fileformat)
                subprocess.Popen([monarchPath,file_open])
                dlg=Desktop(backend='uia').Monarch
                dlg.Dialog.Export.Click()
            except: e` -- the files open however the error message e is printed and i am unable to click on the export button.

Comment: dlg already describes a dialog / window. You probably need dlg.Export.click(). BTW, there are no CamelCase() methods for “uia” backend, we use PEP8 coding style wherever possible.

Comment: Tried dlg.Export. Click did not work.

Comment: Tried another file that i have`dlg=Desktop(backend='uia').Datawatch_Monarch
                dlg.Resolve_Missing_Model_Files.OK.OKStatic.click_input()`. Based on the control identifier for this file. I was able to find the hireracy. However the click_input is not working. There is no error that shows up. I even tried OK.click_input. No avail.

Comment: Tried this`subprocess.Popen([monarchPath,file_open])
                sleep(30)
                dlg=Desktop(backend='uia').Datawatch_Monarch
                dlg.Resolve_Missing_Model_Files.OK.invoke()
                dlg.Export.invoke()`. It worked fine till the pop was there. Then when i tried to click on the Export Menu option in the next part it says ''Datawatch_Monarch' in 'dict_keys'. However it is giving me file name in the match error section. How could i avoid this error.

Comment: This is how the file reflect `'Datawatch Monarch™ - ICR525.xprj - Exempt..., ICR525.xmod'` when i `print (dlg.window_text())`

Comment: When title is changing, you have to make new window specification or use regular expression: dlg = Desktop(backend=“uia”).window(title_re=“Datawatch Monarch.*”)

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Thanks for all the suggestions. I was able to make the code work with your inputs. Do review the below code and let me know if it could be made better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Vasily for the suggestions. Below is my entire code that works.

```
import os
import shutil
from pywinauto.application import Application
from pywinauto import Desktop
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from os import walk
from os.path import splitext
import subprocess
import time
from time import sleep

monarch_files = r'C:\Health Check\Support Monarch Project'
monarchPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Datawatch Monarch 14\DWMonarch.exe'
fileformat ='xprj'
fileformat2='dprj'

rundate = date.today()

job_name = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Check\Job Name.xlsx',
                     sheet_name = 'JobName',
                     header = 0
                     )
for index , row in job_name.iterrows():
    jobname = row['JobName']
    filename=row['ReportName']

    for file_name in dolv_files:
        fname=file_name.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
        if fname==filename:
            print(jobname)
            file_open = os.path.join(monarch_files,jobname + "." + fileformat)
            file_open1 = os.path.join(monarch_files,jobname + "." + fileformat2)
            if os.path.exists(file_open):
                subprocess.Popen([monarchPath,file_open])
                sleep(10)
                dlg=Desktop(backend='uia').window(title_re='Datawatch Monarch *')
                sleep(5)
                try:
                    dlg.Resolve_Missing_Model_Files.OK.invoke()
                    dlg=Desktop(backend='uia').window(title_re='Datawatch Monarch *')
                    dlg.Export.invoke()
                    dlg.Select_All_Exports.invoke()
                    dlg.Run_Exports.invoke()
                    sleep(5)
                    dlg.close()
                    try:
                        dlg.No.invoke()
                    except:
                           print('e')
                except:
                    dlg.Export.invoke()
                    dlg.Select_All_Exports.invoke()
                    dlg.Run_Exports.invoke()
                    sleep(5)
                    dlg.close()
                    try:
                        dlg.No.invoke()
                    except:
                            print('e')
            elif os.path.exists(file_open1):
                    subprocess.Popen([monarchPath,file_open1])
                    dlg=Desktop(backend='uia').window(title_re='Datawatch Monarch *')
                    sleep(5)
                    try:
                        dlg.Resolve_Missing_Model_Files.OK.invoke()
                        dlg=Desktop(backend='uia').window(title_re='Datawatch Monarch *')
                        dlg.Export.invoke()
                        dlg.Select_All_Exports.invoke()
                        dlg.Run_Exports.invoke()
                        sleep(5)
                        dlg.close()
                        try:
                            dlg.No.invoke()
                        except:
                               print('e')
                    except:
                        dlg.Export.invoke()
                        dlg.Select_All_Exports.invoke()
                        dlg.Run_Exports.invoke()
                        sleep(5)
                        dlg.close()
                        try:
                            dlg.No.invoke()
                        except:
                            print('e')                       
            else:
                print("File Not Found")
```

Regards,
Ren.

Comment: Hard-coded sleep() calls is not a good practice. It’s better to wait flexibly: dlg.wait(“ready”, timeout=15).

Comment: Thanks will make that change

Comment: By the way, your regexp is not correct: dot means any symbol, star means any amount. If you omit dot, it will match space of any amount.

Comment: Though this regexp may work because the tail is not limited by $ which means end of string. I’d recommend to read more about standard Python module re. It has good docs.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov sure will do. Thanks for you Suggestions and inputs. Has helped me really well.